# Confuse of run Spring boot 1.3.0 application and specify certain profile

Tags: spring-boot

When I use spring boot 1.3.0 rc1, when run application by

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

in console it will output

```
no profile actived
```

when you run application with

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring.profiles.active=test
```

in console, in will output

```
profile test are activated
```

But yesterday when I changed to 1.3.0 release and run application in production,

```
java -Dspring.profiles.active=production -jar myapp.jar
```

I can't find above output in console. 
In addition, I think it will only load appication-production.properties if you specified production profile, but it not, it still load application.properties. 
So all these let me feel confuse and mislead me think prodcution profile cannot effect and run application by this way that is `java -jar your.jar` could not support `-Dspring.profiles.active`, meantime my colleague waiting for using my service so it give me many pressure.

Can anyone could explain it ?

Comment: The output will only appear in the logfile, if the INFO log level for your application class is enabled. Have you made sure, that this is the case? Of course the property spring.profiles.active is supported, when running an application with `java -jar ...`

Comment: @dunni  Yeah, you are right, I'm wrong. In production I explicitly put a logback-spring.xml, and com.mycompany.* will redirect to file not console. So this log is in file now, e.g. 2015-11-22 23:50:42.307  INFO 9858 --- [           main] com.foo.MyApplication         : The following profiles are active: test. When developing I did not hava any logback configuration , so it default output to console.